# Using Hibernate and LEFT JOIN to load default values from separate table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, left-join

I am writing as system to allow notification options to be set by users.  I have created two classes, Notification and NotificationOption.  Notification is to specify the different events for which a notification is to be sent, as well as default value, and notification option would contain the preferences chosen by the users.  These are the hbm files:

Notification.hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.entities.Notification" table="engine_notification">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">seq_engine_notification_id</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="name" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="descriptor" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="defaultValue" column="default_value"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

NotificationOption.hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.entities.NotificationOption" table="engine_notification_option">
        <composite-id>
           <key-many-to-one name="player"
                     class="com.entities.Profile"
                     foreign-key="id"
                     lazy="false" />
           <key-many-to-one name="notification"
                     class="com.entities.Notification"
                     foreign-key="id"
                     lazy="false" />
       </composite-id>
        <property name="value" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now I don't want to have to create a row in NotificationOption table every time a new Notification type is created, so I want to be able to execute a query on the Notification table which LEFT JOINs NotificationOption on Notification.id = NotificationOption.notification.

Using the following SQL I get the expected result:

```
SELECT * FROM engine_notification n
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT o.* FROM engine_notification_option o WHERE o.player = :playerid) nop
ON n.ID = nop.notification
ORDER BY n.ID;
```

So I added the following to the hbm file:

```
<sql-query name="notificationsForPlayer">
    <return alias="option" class="com.otto.engine.entities.NotificationOption"/>
    <return-join alias="notification" property="option.notification" />
    select
        n.id as {notification.id},
        n.name as {notification.name},
        n.descriptor as {notification.descriptor},
        n.default_Value as {notification.defaultValue},
        nop.player as {option.player},
        nop.value as {option.value}
    from engine_notification n
    left join (select o.* from engine_notification_option o where o.player = :playerID) nop
    on n.id = nop.notification
    order by n.ID
</sql-query>
```

This however is giving me the following:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

Any idea how to fix it, or a different solution to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess `select o.*` in the join is the problem. This kind of a join is not really standard.

How about this select:

```
select
    n.id as {notification.id},
    n.name as {notification.name},
    n.descriptor as {notification.descriptor},
    n.default_Value as {notification.defaultValue},
    nop.player as {option.player},
    nop.value as {option.value}
from engine_notification n
left join engine_notification_option nop
on n.id = nop.notification
where nop.player = :playerID
order by n.ID
```

Comment: it's not the same, I believe. you see, `where` will run on the joined result set and those records without the corresponding `nop` will come with `null`s. The `where` will then check for `nop.player`, won't find it, and will throw all those records away. This version will essentially do an `INNER JOIN`. The original version was different in a way that first it filtered the `nop` down  to those players in question and then left joined to it from the main `engine_notification` table. I hope my explanation makes sense

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was thinking of an inner join (where the two selects would produce the same result), but in fact left join means an outer join.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Johanna, but as Pavel pointed out the results are in fact different. This query also works but gives the same error
    `select
            n.id as {notification.id},
            n.name as {notification.name},
            n.descriptor as {notification.descriptor},
            n.default_Value as {notification.defaultValue},
            nop.player as {option.player},
            nop.value as {option.value}
        from engine_notification n
        left join engine_notification_option nop
        on n.id = nop.notification
        and nop.player = :playerID`